# ‘から’ と‘ですから’ と、どちらが正しいですか。

Tags: orthography

例えば、あのレストランは料理も美味しいし、雰囲気もいいから、大人気です。
疑問は以下:　このフレーズの中で、どうして“いいから”を使ったんですか。“いいですから”を使うのではないですか。そうだったら、“大人気だ”になりますか。
教えてください。

Comment: 「美味しいし」が「美味しいですし」じゃないところは気にならなかったんですね・・・＾＾

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「あのレストランは料理も美味しいし、雰囲気も**いいから**、大人気です。」で十分自然です。「～～**だ**から～～**です**。」というふうに、文末だけ丁寧形にして大丈夫です。

「あのレストランは料理も美味しいし、雰囲気も**いいですから**、大人気です。」でも別にいいのですが、特に「～から」の部分を丁寧形にする必要はないと思います。

もちろん、「あのレストランは料理も美味しいし、雰囲気も**いいから**、大人気**だ**。」と、全体を普通形にしても大丈夫です。

（ただし、「あのレストランは料理も美味しいし、雰囲気もいい**です**から、大人気**だ**。」とするのはおかしいです。）